# Equivalent of c# BitArray.CopyTo of java BitSet

Tags: java, c#, bitset, bitarray

I want to translate the following c# code into java code, but i cannot find the equivalent of copyTo of Java BitSet

```
public byte [] translate(BitArray mask)
    {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[(mask.Length + 7) >> 3];
        mask.CopyTo(tmp, 0);
        return tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you wouldn't even need to write your own method to do that - you could just call [`BitSet#toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray--). I.e., in your case, just use `mask.toByteArray()`.